# how do I activate an angular method when navigated to from a specific page

Tags: angular, ionic4

What I am trying to accomplish is to when I navigate to PageOne from PageTwo it will fire a method addSomthing() {}.  But I do not want to fire the method when navigating from PageThree.

is there a way to use NavigationExtras from @angular/router to accomplish this.

.ts

```
goToPageOne(passed_number: string) {
  let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    state: {
      severityNumberPass: passed_number
      // add something to fire method addSomething
    } 
  };
  this.router.navigate(['/PageOne'], navigationExtras);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this but with the brief description you provide I would use `CanDeactivate` or `CanActivate` methods

Both are interface that you implement as a service on angular and set them a router level:

```
interface CanActivate {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
             , state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean
}
```

Implemented like:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SomeServiceGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
     //--> someMethod() could be invoked here
    console.log('Some validation can go here #canActivate called');
    return true;
  }
}
```

In the routes it is configured like

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppComponent },
  { 
    path: 'other', 
    component: OtherComponent, 
    canActivate: [SomeServiceGuard] //<--- here
  },
```

Comment: Thank you.  This looks like it will work if I do my end.